# Install phalcon with PHP 7 on Debian 8

Tags: php, phalcon, debian-jessie

As per [Phalcon download page](https://phalconphp.com/en/download/linux), Phalcon for PHP 7 (php7.0-phalcon) is available for Debian 9+ versions only. Is there any way to install the same php7.0-phalcon on Debian 8 (with any .deb package available on [packagecloud.io](https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable)) ?

I don't want to use the usual git repository installation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to download the package directly from PackageClound:

- https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable?filter=debs

Comment: Thanks klay. If I download any .deb package for PHP7-Phalcon and try to install it on Debian 8, will it not check the OS compatibility considering php7.0-phalcon is available for Debian 9+ only,?

Comment: It seems it is it https://packagecloud.io/phalcon/stable/packages/debian/jessie/php7.0-phalcon_3.1.2-2+php7.0_amd64.deb